Excel create chart from pivot table Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'SetSourceData' of object '_Chart' failed
Sub CreateChartsFromPivotTables()
    
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim ptPicker As PivotTable
    Dim ptSupDept As PivotTable
    Dim ptTypeOfUse As PivotTable
    Dim rngData As Range
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("DashBoard")
    Set ptPicker = ws.PivotTables("PivotPicker")
    Set ptSupDept = ws.PivotTables("PivotSupDept")
    Set ptTypeOfUse = ws.PivotTables("PivotTypeOfUse")
    
    Set rngData = ptSupDept.TableRange1
    
    Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart2( _
             XlChartType:=XlChartType.xlPie, _
             Left:=ws.Cells(7, 2).Left, _
             Top:=ws.Cells(7, 2).Top, _
             Width:=250, _
             Height:=200)
    
    Set ch = sh.Chart
    
    With ch
        .SetSourceData Source:=rngData
        .SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowPercent, AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False, HasLeaderLines:=False
        .SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    End With
    
    Debug.Print rngData.Address
    
End Sub


I'm encountering an error when using the .SetSourceData method in Excel VBA to set the source data for a chart. Here's what I'm trying to do and the problem I'm facing:

Objective: I want to create charts dynamically in Excel VBA based on the data from PivotTables.
Issue: When I attempt to set the source data for the chart using .SetSourceData, the code throws an error, and the chart doesn't display the expected data.
Context: I have three PivotTables named "PivotPicker", "PivotSupDept", and "PivotTypeOfUse" in my "DashBoard" worksheet. Each PivotTable contains different sets of data.
Question: What could be causing this error with .SetSourceData?


Why are you not using pivot charts instead of regular charts?

Thanks for your reply, but I used Power Query instead and it worked.
